# Cross browser plugin for 3D visualization

Tags: cross-browser, visualization

Whats the best way to write a 3D rendering/visualization control that can meet the following requirements:

1. Can be embedded in an HTML page.
2. Cross-browser: works in as many browsers as possible with minimal porting overhead.
3. Hardware based rendering using OpenGL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WebGL using canvas, no special plugin required: http://www.khronos.org/webgl/
Some examples from Mr Doob: http://mrdoob.com/

Supported Browser: Opera new rel, IE9, Chrome, Firefox and all browser that support html5 and canvas.

Another solution is in simple flash, using some rendering engine like papervision, http://away3d.com/ or the impressive http://alternativaplatform.com/.

And a last one solution can be Java using OpenGL wrapper like http://lwjgl.org/ or 3d engine like: http://jmonkeyengine.com/, both usable as applet or webstart

Comment: WebGL browser compatibility not quite what you claim: http://caniuse.com/#feat=webgl